# Android - Creating a JSON Array in an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to create an array like this:

```
[
  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "400"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "200"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "200"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "100"
    }
  ]
]
```

I have a feeling that it's a simple problem with my JSON logic but i'm getting it wrong somewhere.

Here is my code:

```
    JSONArray outer = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray orows = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray inner = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray trows = new JSONArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        String temprow = 10 + "" + qid + "" + i;
        int rid = Integer.parseInt(temprow);

        final TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
        tr.setId(rid);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        for (int cols = 0; cols < columnHeaders.size(); cols++) {

            int cid = Integer.parseInt(tempcol);

            // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
            final EditText labelTV = new EditText(context);
            labelTV.setId(cid);

            if (answers.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("TABLES: Answer Empty");
                labelTV.setText(columnHeaders.get(cols));
            } else {
                JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
                for (int z = 0; z < answers.size(); z++) {
                    String ans = answers.get(z);
                    String[] parts = ans.split("<:>");
                    int col = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    int row = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                    String text = parts[2];

                    if (labelTV.getId() == col && tr.getId() == row) {
                        labelTV.setText(text);
                        try {
                            test.put("id", col);
                            test.put("value", text);
                            trows.put(test);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        inner.put(trows);
        orows.put(inner);
    }
    outer.put(trows);
    System.out.println("JSON outer IS: " + outer.toString());
}
```

The output that i'm getting is:

```
JSON outer IS: [[{"id":206780,"value":"p1"},{"id":206781,"value":"n1"},
{"id":206782,"value":"d1"},{"id":206780,"value":"p2"},
{"id":206781,"value":"n2"},{"id":206782,"value":"d2"},
{"id":206780,"value":"p3"},{"id":206781,"value":"n3"},
{"id":206782,"value":"d3"},{"id":206780,"value":"p4"},      
{"id":206781,"value":"n4"},{"id":206782,"value":"d4"},
{"id":206780,"value":"p5"},{"id":206781,"value":"n5"},
{"id":206782,"value":"d5"}]]
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

**SOLUTION. Thanks to ci_**

```
    JSONArray inner = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        JSONArray trows = new JSONArray();

        String temprow = 10 + "" + qid + "" + i;
        int rid = Integer.parseInt(temprow);
        // Create a TableRow and give it an ID
        final TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
        tr.setId(rid);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

        //TODO: create the JSON object here

        for (int cols = 0; cols < columnHeaders.size(); cols++) {

            String tempcol = 20 + "" + qid + "" + cols;
            int cid = Integer.parseInt(tempcol);

            // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
            final EditText labelTV = new EditText(context);
            labelTV.setId(cid);

            if (answers.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("TABLES: Answer Empty");
                labelTV.setText(columnHeaders.get(cols));
            } else {
                JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
                for (int z = 0; z < answers.size(); z++) {
                    String ans = answers.get(z);
                    String[] parts = ans.split("<:>");
                    int col = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    int row = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                    String text = parts[2];

                    //set the answer from the prefilled database
                    if (labelTV.getId() == col && tr.getId() == row) {
                        labelTV.setText(text);
                        try {
                            test.put("id", col);
                            test.put("value", text);
                            trows.put(test);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        inner.put(trows);
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to initialize `trows` inside your outer `for` loop, and then `inner` should be your final output. I can't test this right now, but it seems worth a shot.

Comment: @ci_ you're a genius. That was wrecking my head for ages. Submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `trows` inside your outer for loop, and then `inner` would be your final output.

Since you are currently initializing `trows` outside the loop it never gets "reset" between loop iterations, and your final `outer.put(trows)` is just an array with a single element of `trows`.